# How to make a variable column flexbox for responsive design

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive-design, media-queries, multiple-columns

I want to change the number columns to 12 when the screen size is greater 1200px, and I am not getting more than 11 columns. There is always space left for the 12th column but still the 12th column is in the next row.

This flex box contains single column I am using 12 such columns

```html
<div class="flx">
        <div class="col body1 text-justify">
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni
                accusamus, atque unde
                itaque
                labore ex quod expedita nisi cumque, ipsum consequatur dolorum numquam error exercitationem eligendi!
                Labore
                illum dolorum vero.
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And here is the css

```css
@media only screen and (min-width:1200px) {
    .flx>.col {
         flex-basis: calc(100%/12);
      
        

    }
}

.flx {
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}
.text-justify{text-align:justify;}

.body1 {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.00078125rem;//This is because I am using calc() in scss
}
.body1:first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.col{box-sizing:border-box;border:2px dashed aquamarine;}
```